# When adding a column, how to specify a named constraint for the default value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a post-deploy migration script to run sql commands from command line when the project is deployed.

When creating a table in sql server:

```
CREATE TABLE [test] (
    [id] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    [somefield] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
    PRIMARY KEY ([id])
)
```

If I want to drop the column `somefield` I get a message from sql server along the lines of `The object 'DF__test__somefiel__3C74E891' is dependent on column 'somefield'`. The letter/number sequence at the end of the message is generated by the server so I can't predict what it will be. What I have to do is copy that constraint name, and drop the constraint before I can drop the column. This is a manual action that I want to remove.

#### Question

Is there a way, when creating the table, to name the constraint so I can automate the drop of the constraint before the drop of the column?

Comment: You can give the constraint a name (`constraint def_somefield default`).  That is beside the point, actually.  Why do want to delete columns?  That is generally a bad practice in relational databases.

Comment: I am developing a new feature and added a bunch of columns to a table. Thought about it for a bit, and decided it would be better if those fields were in a table by themselves. Tried to drop the columns and hit this issue (again- this has been a recurring issue for me).

Comment: I would suggest that you recreate the table and load the data into it afresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE [test] (
    [id] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    [somefield] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL constraint [Desired Name] DEFAULT 'y',
    PRIMARY KEY ([id])
)
```

Comment: Hint: if you're posting code, you ought to highlight the block of code and hit the `{}` button. It makes the code show up nicely in your answer and turns on syntax highlighting for it too. Whilst you're editing, you may want to add a small amount of commentary to explain *what you have changed*. Code only answers don't tend to be generally useful since even if they do fix the original asker's question, it may not be clear to future visitors how to apply your answer generally to other problems.